# Map path to different domain

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect

I want to be able to map a path to a different domain but keep the original address in the address bar. Is there a way to code this or is it in IIS. I preferably would like a coded method if possible.

I have a link whose href is like this "http://www.example.com/invproxy.aspx?id=1&batch=1".
I want to have that map to "http://www.otherdomain.com/Files/TheFileRequest.aspx".

I generate the path to map to using the querystring of the original request. It works with Server.Transfer or Response.Redirect but i want the address bar to still say the originally requested URL. Is this possible?

Thanks

EDIT: I have solved the issue (probably not the most economical way) but below is the code I am using in the Page_load event of invproxy.aspx

```
// Just test file, no code to select path yet.
string requestPath = "http://www.otherdomain.com/Files/TestFile.pdf";

// Setup the request for the PDF File
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(requestPath);

// Get the response from otherdomain.com
HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

// Assign the invproxy response the PDF ContentType
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

// Get the body of the response in a stream object
Stream s = resp.GetResponseStream();

// Create a byte array to  be read into from the stream
byte[] buffer = new byte[resp.ContentLength];

int position = 0;
while (true)
{
   //Read bytes one by one, slow but causes errors trying to read the whole thing.
   //I need to use chunks here.
   int b = s.ReadByte();
   if (b == -1)
   {
       //This is the end of the stream
       break;
   }
   else
   {
       //Set the byte at the current position to the value just read
       buffer[position] = (byte)b;

       //Advance the position by one.
       position++;
   }
}
//breakpoint debugging
string sa = Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer);

//Write the file to the invproxy response.
Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
```

EDIT: Just to the add the finished result, I get my PDF document displayed in a new tab in the browser (where compatible) with the address bar saying http://www.example.com/invproxy?myquerystring

Comment: Does otherdomain.com live on the same server, or do you otherwise control it?

Comment: Yes, they are both running on my VPS and I control both of them.

Comment: I probably didn't quite understand 100% what you're trying to do, but that technique should give you the pieces of the current URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the response above, I'd suggest using an [IFrame](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) to load the page that you actually want inside of the page whose URL you want the end-user to see.  Keep in mind, this may have knock-on effects depending on how complex the contained page is.

Comment: Ok, so just to complicate it up a bit, the actual content that is being served will be a PDF document. For browsers that dont have inbuilt PDF viewers this is not a concern as the file will just download instead of opening in a page. But for browsers that do support it I want to show the PDF but have the URL as above. I am using target="_blank" on my link so a new tab is always opened.

Comment: That should still work, but if that is all you are trying to accomplish, then you can change the content type to application/pdf and stream the PDF bytes to the Response.  Here's a link on how to do the streaming: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306654

Comment: PDFs can be served to the user in 3 ways generally ... using a PDFViewer.aspx .. where you steam bytes (aka the PDF file) to the user .. serve the file itself with an HTTP handler with a *.pdf extension ... or embedding the PDFViewer into an object--as strict HTML (OR iframe--transitional HTML) .. if you need examples, I have some of each, but they're in VB.NET .. although there's a tool to get the code in C# very easily

Comment: Alright thanks to Chris Shain and Mr MacGyver I have been able to get my answer. I will update my post to show the code I am using.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string newParamName = "QueryParam";
string newParamValue = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Request.QueryString("queryValue").ToString());
Uri uri = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url;
string url = uri.Scheme + "://" + "www.otherdomain.com" + "/Files/TheFileRequest.aspx" + "?" + newParamName + "=" + newParamValue;
HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(url);
```

.. you can make it more sophisticated.. just showing you how to retrieve query string parameters and values in the current URL if necessary